# KDB copy one table's schema (meta) to another table's

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to map one table's schema to another table,

For instance, I have `t1` and `t2`, which have exact column names and order but different datatype, but I want `(meta t2)~meta t1. //1b`.

My idea is to copy datatype string of `t1` using `meta`, say it's `"SFFFFFJJJ"`. Then store `t2` to .csv and read it with `"SFFFFFJJJ"`. This works but not smart, could anyone come up with better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on the same principle as you mention, without the need to save the csv-formatted table:

```
{(upper (0!meta y)`t;enlist",")0:","0:x}[t1;t2]
```

This will return the table `t1` but with the schema of `t2`.

Here, `","0:x` is [Prepare Text](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/file-text/#prepare-text) which converts the table into a list of strings, with data delimited by commas. The `(...;...)0:` is [Load CSV](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/file-text/#load-csv) where the types are being supplied `t2`'s meta table.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the meta of one table to cast the other table:

`t2:flip(exec upper t from meta t1)$string flip t2`

Comment: This is nicer to look at and faster than mine ^